# What technology do we lack, preventing us from the colonization of space?

Tags: colonization, technology, research

I mean the technology that will facilitate multi-planetary life. There is definitely a financial feasibility concern with existing tech, but what technical developments remain to achieve this milestone?

Comment: Cheap rockets...

Comment: Space is too big and empty for a complete colinization of space. There are not many habitable planets of our solar system. Gas giants are not useful, also the very hot inner planets like Mercury and Venus.

Comment: I was just about to post an answer to this. There are many hurdles, but the key one would be a self sufficient colony on the moon of a size large enough that infrastructure exists for assembling spacecraft in-situ. I also had a paragraph on how you might get to that point through robotic moon colonisation.

Comment: Uwe - by that criteria, we haven't colonised Australia because the interior still remains mostly devoid of humans.

Comment: It could be done today but it would be too expensive

Comment: I like the work 'complete' in the question

Comment: This question depends on how you define "colonization of space". That could mean anything between a small group of people living in low Earth orbit with regular supply flights (we are already there) to humans living all around the observable universe (according to our current understanding of physics, this isn't going to happen).